# Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: Cannot connect to SMTP server

Tags: c#, asp.net

i didn't understand why i got this type of error.

> Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: Cannot connect to SMTP server

```
MailMessage objeto_mail = new MailMessage();

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 25;
client.Host = "webmail.domain.com";
client.Timeout = 1000000;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Alert@domain.com", "****");
objeto_mail.From = new MailAddress("Alert@domain.com.com");
objeto_mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("Alert@domain.com"));
objeto_mail.Subject = "Password Recover";
objeto_mail.Body = "Message";
client.Send(objeto_mail);
```

Comment: Basically, it means what it says.  Your client cannot talk to the email server.  It could be a firewall issue, or you could have the hostname or port incorrect, or the email server could be down.  Or there simply could be no public (SMTP) email server at that address.

Comment: Check firewall settings

Comment: yes, now what i do ??

Comment: *"yes, now what i do ??"* - You investigate .....

Comment: You also have conflicting settings: `UseDefaultCredentials = true` and then setting `Credentials`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are attempting to connect to an email service on a host that is offline ... or doesn't exist:

```
$ telnet webmail.domain.com 25
Trying 66.11.232.201...
telnet: connect to address 66.11.232.201: No route to host
$
```

Note that is is on *my* system which doesn't have any firewall rules blocking out-going connections on port 25.